# how to get output when user just presses enter in c++

Tags: c++, coordinates, enter

I am trying to build a simple code that gives the coordinates in two dimensions after you put some direction input.
The problem is I don't know how to give the proper output when the user just presses enter. This should be (0,0) because if the user just presses enter it means he has not changed the coordinates. How can I know if the user has just pressed enter and give the proper output accordingly?

This is the code I have done:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    string direction;

if( cin >> direction) {
    if( !direction.empty() ) {
        // handle input correctly
        // Interpret directions
        for (int i = 0; i < direction.length(); i++) {
            if (direction[i] == 'e') a++;
            else if (direction[i] == 's') b++;
            else if (direction[i] == 'w') a--;
            else if (direction[i] == 'n') b--;
        }
    }
    else if (direction.empty()) cout << "(0,0)" << endl;
}

// Output coordinates
cout << "(" << a << "," << b << ")" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation `cin >> direction;` ignores spaces and also empty lines. Here the string `direction` is not empty whitespace terminated word.

It is possible to read entire line using `std::getline`. This function reads line from stream and also it reads empty lines.

So, the solution:

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
string direction;

getline(cin, direction);

if(!direction.empty()) {
    // Interpret directions
    for (int i = 0; i < direction.length(); i++) {
        if (direction[i] == 'e') a++;
        else if (direction[i] == 's') b++;
        else if (direction[i] == 'w') a--;
        else if (direction[i] == 'n') b--;
    }
}
// else is not needed, since here a = 0 and b = 0.

// Output coordinates
cout << "(" << a << "," << b << ")" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is wrap an `if` around your attempt to get input, then if that succeeds, check whether or not the string the input is put in is empty or not.  If it is empty you know that the user pressed enter without giving any other input.  In code that would be something like:

```
if( cin >> input) {
    if( !input.empty() ) {
       // handle input correctly
    }
}
```

If you want to know why it's done that way, google it in the "C++ super FAQ" at [isocpp.org](http://isocpp.org).

Comment: updated my code but still doesn't output the (0,0). Why?

Comment: I don't know.  If the code above is the exact code you're compiling then you're calling main within itself which is... incorrect and will lead to a stack overflow.  You'll have to debug your code, maybe with added printf equivalents to see where what's going on.  At the very least, add an else for the case that reading from cin failed and print that (so you can verify that your code really is executing the way you intended)